Debugging Interpenetration in Drake Simulation
I've got a robot simulated in Drake, which I'm driving with a game controller. I'm seeing that the robot is able to interpenetrate with other objects in the scene.
I've uploaded some recordings to this imgur link. In the videos, the meshcat visualzation is shown without and then with the proximity meshes.
In case the link becomes inaccessible, here is a screenshot of the issue, showing the proximity meshes and also the resultant forces.

How can I debug and find the source of this? Ideally I would like the robot to just stop when I attempt to drive it into the table.
Other information:

The URDF for the robot has effort values attached to each joint, so torque limits should be reached before the robot can penetrate the table
The plant is set to use DiscreteContactApproximation.kSAP
The plant timestep is 0.007
It seems only the gripper (robotiq 2f-85) is allowed to penetrate. I've modeled it with BallConstraint and CouplerConstraint since it is not a tree, and I use a DistanceConstraint with spring stiffness to model the passive compliance mechanism.
Only the fingers are problematic. The rest of the gripper does not penetrate easily, as shown in this video.
To implement the controller, I have the following in my plant setup code.

  for i in range(7):
    actuator = plant.GetJointActuatorByName(f"motor{i+1}", xarm7)
    actuator.set_controller_gains(PdControllerGains(p=500, d=50))

I've updated the code to print out the net actuation parameters. There are 8 values, 7 for the arm and then 1 for the gripper.

It looks like the effort limits are being respected. Three joints hit max effort (30 Nm, 30 Nm, 20 Nm) during the interpenetration event.

Okay, so the arm's effort limits are being respected.  That means even within those limits it's able to overcome the contact forces.
I see green arrows in your screenshots.  That means you're using point contact, instead of hydroelastic contact (hydro uses red arrows).  When using point contact, Drake only model a single point of contact for colliding geometries pairs (as compared to multi-point contact, which some other simulators can offer).  That's certainly not helping with your gripper penetration; possibly you could try increasing drake:point_contact_stiffness to help even with point contact.  I imagine a hydroelastic contact would probably generate a more reasonable and stable force profile, though.
In general you'll want to work on tuning the proximity properties (drake:proximity_properties) for the two colliding objects to create the contact forces you're looking for.  Both by switching to hydroelastic models, and by setting appropriate physical constants.

Thanks @jwnimmer-tri. I have turned up the point contact stiffness on my table to 1e30 and it still doesn't prevent the penetration. I have also tried adding hydroelastic properties to all bodies in the URDFs involved, as well as programmatically to table, and using set_contact_model(kHydroelastic), but that threw an error "Requested contact between two rigid objects (Convex with id 174, Convex with id 126); that is not allowed in hydroelastic-only contact." Using the kHydroelasticWithFallback seems to just use the original point contact model.

The MultibodyPlant docs say: "Effort limits are not enforced, unless PD controllers are defined.".  Assuming you're using your own torque controller to driver the robot (not the implicit PD desired state input port), you need to enforce the effort limits yourself, in your controller.  You can check the MbP's net_actuation output port to see what kind of torques end up being commanded.  If they are exceeding the effort limit you expect to see, that's a starting point for debugging.

Thanks. I think I'm using the PD controller of the plant. In my plant setup I have
actuator.set_controller_gains(PdControllerGains(p=500, d=50)) on each actuator. I've updated my question with this information. And I do use the desired_state_input_port. Is that what you mean by the implicit PD?
Let me check the net_actuation.

Yes, that's implicit PD.  So the effort limits are being respected, as you noted.
